# How to make image form bytes?

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, byte

I download images from the frontend and save on backend as byte[]. Then I return a byte[] to Vue JS.
How can I create image from these bytes?

Comment: what format is the data in javascript?

Comment: @Jaromanda X  image/jpeg

Comment: really? the data you get is "image/jpeg"? I mean you state that you `I return a byte[] to Vue JS` ... so, you have data in some JS variable ... is it a `String` or is it a `Blob` or maybe an `ArrayBuffer` ... i.e. what type of data is it (JS has no such type as whatever the heck `byte[]` is